# Keras neural fails to train / does not improve at all / accuracy (acc.) keeps constant value

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, keras

Sometimes the training fails totally and the accuracy stays constant over the entire training. In the other case, the ANN can adapt perfectly with enough iterations.

My ANN is without any intermediate layer. Only K inputs, and one output. One of the features is exactly the output. This is just a toy model I want to test against my more complex one.
And indeed, the problem shows up too with a "high"-dimonsional input.

I changed also optimizers, learning rate etc. It run on several hosts. The code is a hack but shows the problem.

Can anyone pointing out the problem? Thanks!

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np


model = Sequential()

a = np.array( range(1,100) ) # one vector

#X_train = a                         # is working, OK
X_train = np.squeeze(np.hstack((
                                  a[:,None],
                                  a[:,None]+10,
                                  a[:,None]+20,
                                  a[:,None]+30,
                                  a[:,None]+40,
                                  a[:,None]+50,
                                  a[:,None]+50,
                                  a[:,None]+50,
                                  a[:,None]+50,
                                  a[:,None]+100,
                                  a[:,None]+100,
                                  a[:,None]+100,
                                  a[:,None]+100,
                                  a[:,None]+100,
                                  a[:,None]+100,
                                  a[:,None]*10,
                                  a[:,None]*10,
                                  a[:,None]*10,
                                  a[:,None]*10,
                                  a[:,None]*100,
                                  a[:,None]*100,
                                  a[:,None]*100,
                                  a[:,None]*100,
                                  a[:,None]*100,
                                  a[:,None]*100,
                                  a[:,None]*100,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01,
                                  a[:,None]*0.01
                    )))

model.add(Dense( 1, input_dim=np.size(X_train[0,:]))   # in
model.add(Dense(1,activation="relu"))     # out

'''
https://keras.io/optimizers/#adam
'''

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(
              loss="mean_squared_error",
              optimizer=optimizer)
              #metrics=['accuracy'])
Y_train = a

model.fit( X_train, Y_train,
           nb_epoch=200,
           batch_size=10 )

X_test = X_train      # training equals test set
Y_test = Y_train
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=16)
print(str(score))

outputPred = model.predict(X_test)

print("X_train:" +str(X_train))
print("Y_train:" +str(Y_train))
print("prediction is")
print(str(outputPred))
```

Comment: (1) Code is a bit ugly and hard to reason about your experiments with those comments/outcommented parts (2) ```One of the features is exactly the output.``` does not necessarily help here because your NN is too simple to switch on these features. It needs kind of using all features weighted somehow (similar to linear-regression). It might be not that simple to reason about the possible theoretical loss which could be obtained. (3) You should really preprocess your input, at least center it (subtract mean). Maybe even standardize it. This should make it more robust.

Comment: thanks..I understand these things. But this does not explain why there are only two outcomes of training: perfect vs. nothing optimised.

Comment: BTW, normalization to e.g. [0,1] does not seem to alter the condition for training. Also, if many of the dimensions are the output itself, it does not work!

Comment: Well... if you just want some keyword on the why: local-optimum. The normalization you propose is also different than what i proposed.

Comment: The idea was right, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the optimizer demands a proper format. Even though the input is in the domain [0,K], it could not be optimized with the activation "relu".

Normalization helps: Centering input and output data, brings up improvement. Furthermore, but not necessary, a smaller range e.g. with wdith of 1.

The activation "**relu**" works only with such nice data format.

The activation "**tanh**" converges way better in small ranges (max-min=1).

In the shown extreme test case, "**linear**" yields abruptly to a convergence.

---

To sum up, the training can fail if the data is in a **format** which the optimizer cannot handle. Even it should be easily possible such as a 1:1 map between one input and the single output.

Consider **compatible activations** at the right layers. Take into account that the success depends on optimizer, loss function and metric too.

Comment: This answer is at least very misleading and not really based on a good understanding of NNs. The sum-up part is especially bad (when connected to the work/environment of the question). The approach of the last sentence is always right, but seldom the most critical thing to do (except for the final layer). You really should work through a general machine-learning tutorial to learn about model-capabilities and maybe even [VC-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_theory), but at least [VC-dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But, "relu" could do the job perfectly. That is one line to prove mathematically. It is a issue of the special test case and the optimizer.